# ChildIOException when creating a subdirectory of a subdirectory

Tags: snakemake

I'm looking for maybe, help or understanding toward an error.

I have an ChildIO exception when i create a subdirectory in a directory created on a previous subdirectory created by a rule.

Basicly, i've a rule that'll create a directory with a couple subdirectories and files through a first script. Then, my 2nd rule will take one pecular subdirectory and make another inside the parent directory of the subdirectory through another script. And my 3rd rule is taking on that new subdirectory, and make in it another (with others files).

I don't understand, why my rule 2 work, while the third don't

My workflow is as following :

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

dirname = config["dirname"].values()
script_dir = config["script_dir"]

rule all:
# Contain all output
    input:
        expand(["{dirname}/GFF/","{dirname}/GFF/final_gffs/", "{dirname}/GFF/roary_results/",
        "{dirname}/GFF/roary_results/pangenome_multifastas/"], dirname=dirname)

rule prepa_gff:
# Transform gbff files to gff through prepare to roary
    input:
        expand("{dirname}/GenBank/",dirname=dirname)
    output:
        gff_dir = directory(expand("{dirname}/GFF/",dirname=dirname)),
        gff_fin = directory(expand("{dirname}/GFF/final_gffs/",dirname=dirname))
    params:
        script_dir = script_dir
    message:
        "Converting gbff files into gff files."
    run:
        for dir in dirname:
            shell("cd {script_dir} && python3 prepare_to_roary.py -i {dir}/GenBank -o {dir}/GFF")

rule roary:
# Launch roary, with the script itself launching the cluster for operating
    input:
        rules.prepa_gff.output.gff_fin
    output:
        dir = directory(expand("{dirname}/GFF/roary_results/", dirname=dirname)),
    params:
        script_dir = script_dir
    message:
        "Launching roary."
    run:
        for i in input:
            shell("cd {script_dir} && python3 roary_launcher.py -i {i}")

rule cluster_fasta:
# Launch the script for creating multi-fasta files corresponding to each identified cluster
    input:
        rules.roary.output.dir
    output:
        directory(expand("{dirname}/GFF/roary_results/pangenome_multifastas/", dirname=dirname))
    params:
        script_dir = script_dir
    message:
        "Clustering in multi-fasta format."
    run:
        for i in input:
            shell("cd {script_dir} && python3 pan_genome_maker_T.py -i {i}")

ChildIOException:
File/directory is a child to another output:
('../Sero3/GFF/roary_results', roary)
('../Sero3/GFF/roary_results/pangenome_multifastas', cluster_fasta)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict order of execution if the rules have no dependencies. Your `rule all:` specifies the target of 3 directories, but they are nested, so only the last is needed.

From the point of view of Snakemake, the goal is to create one directory: `"{dirname}/GFF/roary_results/pangenome_multifastas/"`, and the rest is irrelevant. What does *prepare_to_roary.py* script do? I don't know, Snakemake neither.

Try to rethink your task in terms of the files that your pipeline produces, and disambiguate your intention.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! For the rule all, indeed, i addet brick by brick those target, and i didn't realized i could just let the last.

I'll try to rethink